# SVN Command Clean List of Files Changed Between Branches

Tags: linux, svn

I'm trying to find the proper command in subversion to see a list of all the files that have changed (don't need to see the changes really) between branch/tag A and branch/tag B, etc.

Answer (score 9):

How about `svn diff --summarize <A> <B>`

You may also use `svn diff --help` to get more options

and `svn status --help` to get explanations on all possible modification description letters ('A', 'M' etc.)

Comment: Thank you. The summarize switch works great but I end up with this huge list with A's and D's in the first column. What does that signify? I can't find much in the man pages.

Comment: They signify A - Add, D- delete, M - modify

Answer (score 2):

[SVN DIFF](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re09.html) is what you are looking for.  Should be able to specify the urls to the different branches

svn diff http://domain.com/tags/A http://domain.com/tags/B

Comment: That works but I get a very ugly dump of all the actual changes. I just want to see the files.

Comment: Oh, not sure in that case.  I imagine you could pipe it to grep, but that might get nasty.

Comment: To show only the file names that differ, pipe the output through cut. The first 7 columns of each output line show the file status descriptors, so to show only the file names use the following command:

`svn diff --summarize <A> <B> | cut -c 9-`